# Jenkins build invokes Git installation set up dialog multiple times

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am Triggering Jenkins build with Git as my repository.

When i trigger Jenkins build ,Git installation set up dialog comes up multiple times .

I have GIT already installed in my machine.
(I have provided Git exe path in 'Jenkins-configuration-Path to Git executable')

What need to be done to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Ganesh

Comment: Have you set up git on all of your slaves? and do you use the git plugin

Comment: I am not using git slaves. Ya i have installed git plugin in Jenkins